I'm trying to make identity validation of onboarding clients, using Aadhar, need an alternative process if OTP verifications fails?
There are many vendors offering options for identity validation using image matching, live photos with uploaded documents. However, in most cases, the photos on documents and personal identity cards are not updated, resulting in inaccurate solutions for this validation.
Regarding the Aadhar eKYC login process, there are cases where some clients have not linked their mobile numbers with their Aadhar cards, leading to significant OTP validation issues.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
